# Google APIs Verification

Tags: google-maps, google-api, verification

I am attempting to add a Google maps to a website and allow users to insert their postcode to get directions to my client.

Currently I can't manage to make the map visible, the website although under development IS hosted and I have my own unique api key.

Is there more verification necessary? I read something about meta tags but was unsure how to get a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your expecting or are getting more than 25000 hits a day, you don't need an API key for the current version of google maps, so requesting it with http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true should work then use a library like this should get it to work http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_tutorial

Follow that tutorial and you'll have it running in no time.